# Logging for getting report in ASP.NET MVC 3 site

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I have created a site using asp.net mvc3 and I have some action in my site like submitting special data, register entrance of people and ...
I need to make system able to make report depend on users actions. so I need to save log information in database.
my idea is to make 2 entities:

- general action description
- log event

like below:

```
LogAction: 
int id
string action

LogEvent:    
int id
int LogActionID
int userID
string extraDescription
```

for this idea I have to create 2 other entity in my Entity framework.
I want to know that is this idea ok or there is better idea for getting report of system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a DateTime property for the LogEvent, but all in all this is a good design.
On an additional note, I'd recommend the use of some sort of AOP framework like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) for the actual logging code